# differences between project structure created by editor.swagger.io and swagger project create command

Tags: swagger, apigee, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor, openapi

Has anyone tried generating project skeleton by editor.swagger.io by using YAML file ? and then tried unit and integration testing on it without editing the project structure.
 
I tried both ,command line and editor.swagger.io , to create swagger project but the project structure is different and inconsistent. take a look at below one.
[image: editor.swagger.ioimage]

this project structure i got by using editor.swagger.io ,create server code , node js.

and the below one i got while using 'swagger project create prjName' command.
[image: swagger cli]

why they are different ? 
is there any way to make it consistent in both ways ?

Comment: the reason for asking this one is because I am not able to perform unit testing and integration testing without changing project structure provided by editor.swagger.io. I need to maintain it something similar to the below one image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are completely different projects.  The `swagger-node` project is self-contained, and includes an editor as well.  The online version does not, and uses the swagger-codegen project to write the project files.

Not to jump ahead too far, but expect the swagger-node project style to change substantially soon.